# Css table-cell on 2 rows

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to put on two rows a table css generated?

Here you can view a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/EHdLt/2/

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
    <li>Sixth</li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I would like to put "Fourth", "Fifth" and "Sixth" on a second row (so on a new line), without doing another list ("ul")

Comment: Use table, then you don't have to use more ul tag and use tr instead.

Answer (score 2):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHdLt/9/) <--- use this one ideally

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin:0;
        padding:0;
    border:0;
}
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width:33%;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #666;
}

ul li:nth-child(4){
    clear:both;
}
```

**OTHER (NOT SO NICE) SOLUTIONS**

this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHdLt/6/)

or this (probably not this but it's there anyway) [anotherfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHdLt/8/)

Comment: the first is quite similar to the solution that i want, however i can't specify the width of a cell. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made another `<ul>` here http://jsfiddle.net/PHPglue/ee68V/ .